# Why did Henry Cameron tell Roark that it was all worth it?

Tags: ayn-rand, the-fountainhead

At one point, Henry Cameron tried to fire Howard Roark and get him to quit architecture because he knew what kind of a struggle Howard would have later. However, towards the end of his life he told Howard:

> Do you remember the day when I tried to fire you? Forget what I said to you then. It was not the whole story... Don't be afraid... it was worth it.

Why did he say that? What did he mean by "worth it"?